# Visual Studio how to ifstream in debugging mode

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to open a stream in debugging mode with visual studio but the following piece of code throw an exception meaning that it failed to open :

`ifstream test ("./file");
    if (!test){
        throw runtime_error("failed");
    }`

So how can I make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the file exists. Since it's an `ifstream`, it's trying to open an existing file for input.

If the file doesn't exist, it will fail.

And keep in mind, it will try to open the file in your current directory. That may not be what you think it is, you can (temporarily) use something like `system("cd")` into your code (before the declaration of `test`) to see what it is.

Or, if you prefer not to call an external program, you can look into [_getcwd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf98bd4y%28v=vs.120%29.aspx), which will give you the same information.

Comment: @Wicelo, I meant insert it into your code so you can see what the _actual_ current path is. See the update.

Comment: `system("cd")` prints `Application "\??\C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" found in cache`in console. However if I call `system("cd C:\Path")` then `system("cd")` it still prints the same thing.

Comment: In fact system works but it opens a console very fast I don't have time to read, is it possible to put the console on hold ?

Comment: @Wicelo: `system("cd && pause")` is the first thing I'd try, or just use `_getcwd` as per the link and display it within your app itself.

Comment: Okay nice I was able to pull it out the path was wrong indeed it wasn't in the debug folder as I was expecting. I can't change the path to what I want with system("cd ..\Debug") tho.

Comment: @Wicelo, `system` weaves its magic in a separate process so will not affect the working directory of your executable. Look into `_chdir` instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7fwze1.aspx.